# Python : Randomly choose a boolean from an array and change its value

Tags: python, arrays, random, boolean

I was wondering if it was possible to create a code like the one quoted.

I mean if it is possible to create an array with booleans (False), choose only one (randomly) and change its value (to True) and then be able to use it?

The first random choice should only be done once, when the program is launched.

```
Gentleman = False
Daughter = False
Madam = False

character_list = [Gentleman, Daughter, Madam] # an array with the bools above

for character in characters_list:
    character = random.choice(characters_list) # Randomly pick a character from the list
    character = True # Set the character as True

    if Madam == True:
        ...
        Madam = False
        Daughter = True
        ...

    if Gentleman == True:
        ...
        Gentleman = False
        Madam = True
        ...

    if Daughter == True:
        ...
        Daughter = False
        Gentleman = True
        ...
```

PS: I know my code is wrong but it's just to try to illustrate what I would like to do

Thank you for your help

**Update**

So after trying what is written in the comment, I find myself with a problem

```
Gentleman = False
Daughter = False
Madam = False

character_list = [Gentleman, Daughter, Madam] # an array with the bools above
print(characters_list)
characters_list[random.randint(0, len(characters_list)-1)] = True
print(characters_list)

print("Starting up ...")

if Madam == True:
    print("Hello Madam")
    ...
    Madam = False
    Daughter = True
    ...
```

**Output**

```
[False, False, False]

[False, False, True]

Starting up ...
```

Since I don't go into the `if Madam == True:` I guess I don't quite understand how to use it, what should I do to get my code to understand that the Madam has turned True and goes into the if statement

(Btw I am new to Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an array with booleans (False) and randomly change one of it's value (to True) try:

**Code:**

```
import random

my_list = [False]*5
print(my_list)
my_list[random.randint(0,len(my_list)-1)] = True
print(my_list)
```

**Input**

```
[False, False, False, False, False]
```

**Output**

```
[False, True, False, False, False]
```

**Explanation**

1. Use `randint()` function of the `random` module to randomly select an a number between 0 and `length-1` of your list
2. Use this number as index to replace a random element in your list with a new boolean value

### Update

You code seem to warrant a python `dict` so try modifying the above logic to:

**Code**:

```py
import random

my_dict = {'Gentleman': False, 'Daughter': False, 'Madam': False}
print(my_dict)
my_dict[random.choice(list(my_dict.keys()))] = True
print(my_dict)

if my_dict['Madam'] == True:
    print("Hello Madam")
    my_dict['Madam'] = False
    my_dict['Daughter'] = True

print(my_dict)
```

**Input**:

```
{'Gentleman': False, 'Daughter': False, 'Madam': False}
```

**Output**:

```
# initial values
{'Gentleman': False, 'Daughter': False, 'Madam': False}

# after random value is set to True
{'Gentleman': False, 'Daughter': False, 'Madam': True}

#inside the if condition
Hello Madam
{'Gentleman': False, 'Daughter': True, 'Madam': False}
```

**Explanation**

1. Initialize your elements as a `dict` with values as boolean, rather than list
2. Use `random.choice()` function of the `random` module to randomly select an a key from `dict`
3. Use this key to replace a random boolean in your `dict` with a new boolean value

Comment: I tried to reproduce your explanation but it seems that I do not know how to apply it to my code. I don't understand how to call / use the character which has become True

Comment: @PabloS From whatI understand from the update you want to associate this `boolean` value with a person, you should use a python `dict` for that, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

It's not too complicated. Essentially, what you want to do is pick a random index in the the list, and change that item. For example,

```py
import random

bool_list = [False, False, False]

list_length = len(bool_list)

index = random.randint(list_length)

bool_list[index] = True
```

or, wrapped into a function:

```py
def set_random_true(list_):
    list_len = len(list_)
    index = random.randint(index)
    list_[index] = True
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```py
import random

def set_random_true(list_):
    --snip--

my_list = [False, False, False]
set_random_true(my_list)

print(my_list)
```

This would either print `[True, False, False]`, `[False, True, False]`, or `[False, False, True]`. Hope this helped!